# How to set animation when I changes content in same activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I one activity I am seting different layouts depends on user choice.

For example I have `setContentView(R.layout.main)`,
after that when user choose something I am setting new like `setContentView(R.layout.first)` when next time clicks I am setting `setContentView(R.layout.second)`.

I need to change content in same activity. How to set animation ( something like when I really changing between activities ) when I changes content from main to first and from first to second ?

Answer (score 1):

Let us take this with example.
Suppose we are changing view on press of button,

```
private OnTouchListener touch = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                     loadOutViewAnimation();//
                     loadInViewAnimation();
                  }
            }
    }

    public void loadOutViewAnimation(){
            //considering layout is your root layout
            layout.setAnimation(animation);

    }

    public void  loadInViewAnimation(){
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        //by using findview by id here you will get root layout.
        layout.setAnimation(animation);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using ViewFlipper.....
See this example http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example
I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can used methods from `AnimationUtils` class `makeInAnimation(context, boolean)` and `makeOutAnimation(context, boolean)` to create Animation object. Config it with `setStartTime` and `setDuration` methods. Now you can call `setAnimation` on your view and it will be appearing or/and disappearing with your animation.